# getting an error 'camelize is not a function' in vue 3, vuetify and laravael

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vuetify.js

I am building a web application using VueJS, Vuetify, and Laravel when I suddenly got this error: [this is the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CunJq.png)

```
Uncaught TypeError: camelize is not a function
    at expand_transition_default (expand-transition.ts:16:26)
    at index.ts:26:82
```

I don't what this error means. Please help.

Edit: I got the error after running `npm run build`. The project works perfectly during `npm run build` but when I go back to `npm run dev`, the error pops up. I did not use a function like `camelize` as stated on the error so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the issue? When does this error occur?

Comment: @KiranParajuli I think it happened when I ran `npm run build` to test my project on my android phone. It works perfectly during `npm run build` but when I go back to `npm run dev`, that's when the error pops up. I don't know what the error means because I did not use a function like camelize in my project so I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

This happens forexample when using wrong element (vuetify2) `<v-expansion-panel-content>` instead of the current version one which is (vuetify3) `<v-expansion-panel-text>`.

GithubCopilot is suggesting wrong elements from Vuetify2 all the time! GithubCopilot still does not know Vuetify3. One of the problems is the Vuetify3 documentation, which is a JS SPA/PWA and not readable by crawlers. Vuetify3 really needs a static HTML documentation, like **good old Doxygen** generated pages.